# Express.js: request.path changes from middleware to endpoint

Tags: express

Given this piece of code:

```
function f(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.path);
  next();
}

router.use('/db', f);
  
  router
    .route('*') 
    .get(f);
```

Surprisingly when I make a call to `/db` I see following output:

```
/ --> output from app.use() middleware
/db --> output from GET handler
```

The express.js [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path) do say that:

> When called from a middleware, the mount point is not included in req.path.

however what is surprising is that `req.path` is a variable, so how does it get reset between call to use and call to the GET handler? It looks like express passes a different `req` object in the two calls to `f`. is that correct?

Is there any convenient way for me to get the path that is printed in call to `f` from `app.use()` but in the GET handler? i.e., I want following output:

```
/
/
```

what is the best way to do this?